# Conditional root layout in Next.js 13's app directory?

Tags: next.js

I'm using the new `app/` directory with Next.js 13.4.

Is there a way to do conditional layouts in root `layout.tsx` based on which route I'm on?

The use case is home page and all sub pages share the same layout defined in root `layout.tsx`, except that some sub pages should have a different body background color. Ideally I should set the background color on the `body` tag defined in the root layout.

Is this possible? Is there a prop I can read in the layout, to see which route is being rendered?

I have other similar use cases, so would be nice to have a solution for conditionally rendering layout based on routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following because the other solutions would inherit the body from the root layout (the one in /app)

```
app/
├─ (default)/              
│  ├─ layout.tsx           <- layout for the home page and most of pages
│  ├─ page.tsx             <- this will be your new home (unique, do not define it in other routes)
│  ├─ products/            <- yourwebsite.com/products
│  │  ├─ page.tsx
├─ (alternative)/              
│  ├─ layout.tsx           <- layout with body with red background, or whatever you like, custom header, custom metadata, etc.
│  ├─ special-products/    <- yourwebsite.com/special-products
│  │  ├─ page.tsx
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible yes, you can mark a folder as a route group to prevent the folder from being included in the route's URL path or be nested in the parent layout. More can be found inside the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups).

```
app/
├─ page.tsx
├─ layout.tsx           <- layout for the home page
├─ (shop)/              <- route group, defined by encasing name in ()
│  ├─ layout.tsx        <- layout for all pages in this group
│  ├─ products/
│  │  ├─ page.tsx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage multiple layouts with following way.

```
app/
├─ page.tsx (It contains layout for home + content for home page )  
├─ layout.tsx  (Contains common layout tags like <html><body>...for all pages)
├─ (bluebg)/  (Group folder for the pages having blue bg or different style)
│  ├─ layout.tsx (Some pages having blue bg or style X )
│  ├─ about/
│  │  ├─ page.tsx ( Content of about page with style X layout )
├─ (greenbg)/  (Group folder for the pages having green bg or different style)
│  ├─ layout.tsx (Some pages having green bg or style Y )
│  ├─ contact/
│  │  ├─ page.tsx ( Content of contact page with style Y layout )
```

I hope it will be helpful, let me know if it works.